# head command to skip last few lines of file on MAC OSX

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal, osx-lion

I want to output all lines of a file, but skip last 4, on Terminal.

As per UNIX man page following could be a solution.

`head -n -4 main.m`

**MAN Page:**

> -n, --lines=[-]N
>             print  the first N lines instead of the first 10; with the lead-
>             ing '-', print all but the last N lines of each file

I read man page here. http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?head

But on MAC OSx I get following error.

> head: illegal line count -- -4

What else can be done to achieve this goal?

Comment: Not a criticism; just curious. Where did you read the man page for head? Perhaps not on the Mac OS X computer you're running head on? I ask because the head man page on my Mac OS X computer does not mention the `leading '-'` argument. (see `man head`)

Comment: @btnaka here it is..http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?head. As i not too comfortable with reading and searching on terminal I googled it....

Comment: Ah. Give it a whirl. I think you'll find it pretty easy. To see the man page for any command, type man <command>. For example, to see the head man page, type: man head. Long man pages will be presented in your default pager (probably `less`). To go forward, hit space. To go back, hit b. For more less help, hit h.

Comment: @btanaka it does on mine, see also https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/head.1.html  I am having the same issue btw.

Comment: @btanaka You can access it with `info head` on a Mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `awk` for example:

```
$ cat file
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
$ awk 'n>=4 { print a[n%4] } { a[n%4]=$0; n=n+1 }' file
line 1
line 2
$
```

It can be simplified to `awk 'n>=4 { print a[n%4] } { a[n++%4]=$0 }'` but I'm not sure if all awk implementations support it.

Comment: this prints last two lines. which can be done using tail -2 file

Answer (score 18):

GNU version of `head` supports negative numbers.

```
brew install coreutils
ghead -n -4 main.m
```

Answer (score 3):

A Python one-liner:

```
$ cat foo
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
$ python -c "import sys; a=[]; [a.append(line) for line in sys.stdin]; [sys.stdout.write(l) for l in a[:-4]]" < foo
line 1
line 2
```

Comment: One should not write one-liners in Python o_O