# How to append extra newline on each json with jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

I know that `jq .` makes the json pretty and indented, but I would like to add 2 extra newlines after each json. Meaning:

Input:

```
{"foo": "bar", "say":"what"}
{"foo2": "bar2", "say2":"what2"}
```

Wanted output:

```
{
  "foo": "bar", 
  "say":"what"
}


{
  "foo2": "bar2", 
  "say2":"what2"
}
```

Is that possible with `jq` somehow? I have tried `cat file.json | sed G | jq .` without success and actually I wanted to avoid some `sed` magic thinking that maybe `jq` could do all the work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) is capable of producing such an output in general.

---

- We can use some [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) magic to insert a newline on each line containing just an `}`.

  - `sed 's/^\}/&\n\n/'`
- Since there will be a trailing newline, we'll use `head -c -2` to remove the last lines.

---

Output:

```json
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "say": "what"
}


{
  "foo2": "bar2",
  "say2": "what2"
}
```

---

Example on my local machine:

```
$ cat input.json
{"foo": "bar", "say":"what"}
{"foo2": "bar2", "say2":"what2"}
$
$
$ jq '.' input.json | sed 's/^\}/&\n\n/' | head -c -2
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "say": "what"
}


{
  "foo2": "bar2",
  "say2": "what2"
}
$
```

---

*edit*

- Added `^` to the [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) command to only match `}` *on the start of the line*.

  `sed 's/\}/&\n\n/'` --> `sed 's/^\}/&\n\n/'`

Comment: This can be generalized to handle all other incoming JSON types.

Comment: Thanks for this. It give the desired output. Although the `head` part didn't work for me since I'm working on Mac and the `-n -2` doesn't work as in Linux. Thanks!

Comment: I'm also on mac, it's working fine here. Did use `gsed` tho, maybe that helps!

Comment: The `sed` part worked correctly. It's just the deleting of last 2 lines that don't work for me. I think it's bc of this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206507/head-command-to-skip-last-few-lines-of-file-on-mac-osx

Answer (score 2):

So long as none of the incoming JSON texts is a string, you could write:

```
jq -r '., "", ""' file.json
```

Comment: What do you mean by; "*So long as none of the incoming JSON texts is a string*" ?

Comment: I mean: so long as none of the top-level items in the stream is a JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the output of `jq .` to `sed` as follows:

```
jq . file.json | sed '/}/s//&\n\n/'
```

Comment: Oops: same answer as 0stone0, sorry. He does better because he removes the two trailing blank lines with `head -c -2`

Comment: Always nice to see someone come up with the same answer. You can always hit that upvote button to show OP that it's somehow useful ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using some unreadable perl to only print extra newlines between the closing brace and the opening brace

```sh
jq . file | perl -0777 -pe 's/^\}\n\{/}\n\n\n{/gm'
```